# Where should I add afterLoad to some jquery code

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a piece of javascript to a fancybox image but I'm not sure the correct place to put it. I'd really appreciate it if someone could show me where to add this :

```
afterLoad: function () {
             this.outer.append("Read More");
             }
```

to this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#single_image").fancybox({

        afterShow: function () {
            $(".fancybox-image").wrap($("<a />", {
                href: this.href, //or your target link
                target: "_blank"
           }));
event.preventDefault();
        }

    });

});
```

I've made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/axfzLh7v/1/)

Comment: if `afterLoad` is another option to supply to the `fancybox` function then wouldn't you put it in there?  Where you already have `afterShow`?

Comment: there is no method 'afterload' you can put your function in to the 'aftershow'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add it to the options being passed to `fancybox`:

```
$("#single_image").fancybox({
    afterShow: function () { /.../ },
    afterLoad: function () { /.../ }
});
```